# How to add a div dynamically to a td tag of a datatable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a *div* to *td* tag of a datatable. Here is my HTML code:

```
table = $("#workLocation-table").DataTable({
            data: mainArray,
            "columnDefs": [
                { className: "details-control" , "targets": [0]},
                {
                    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
                },
                {
                "targets": -1,
                "width": "10%",
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": '<div class="edit-wrapper"><span class="icn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" id="edit"></i><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" id="delete"></i></span></div>'
            }]
        });
```

I want to add a div into targets 2 and provide *"over-length"* class to that div.

Comment: What kind of html code is this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var target = document.getElementById("id_of_the_element_inside_which_you_want_to_insert_div");
var d = document.createElement("div"); // Create div dynamically
d.setAttribute("class","over-length"); // Add "over-length" class to the dynamically created div
target.appendChild(d); // Now insert div inside target element
```

Comment: Why don't you use a render function ?

Comment: @PhilMaGeo thank you so much.I solved my issue using render function

Comment: :-) I use it every day :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
table =  $("#workLocation-table").DataTable({
        data: mainArray,
        "columnDefs": [
            { className: "details-control" , "targets": [0]},
            {
                "order": [[1, 'asc']]
            },
            {
                "targets": 2,
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<div class="over-length">'+data+'</div>'
                } 
            },
            {
                "targets": -1,
                "width": "10%",
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": '<div class="edit-wrapper"><span class="icn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" id="edit"></i><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" id="delete"></i></span></div>'
        }]
    });
```